# mysql data sync within different table structure

Tags: mysql

Now, I had two tables of different databases, also different table structure, as is known, that's two same project, name it old and new,  The old project has some user module and it already has some user data, how to export old user table data and import to new user table data. Does have tools or php code can do this? even more modules will do like this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL INSERT INTO SELECT such as:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

Above examples is for two tables in same schema. If your's tables are in separate schema, you should add pre-fix schema_name.table_name on query.
Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: if those tables has relationship,  such as i was inserted into user table a row, then i need this auto-increment id to act as uid, the sub table need this uid and some other old data become a row, how do to do?  on the other way, i can  directly use the old uid insert new user table,  maybe that's not good idea.

Comment: @Carey: As I understand you want to move uid from old table to new table. In this case, you can directly use the old uid insert new user table as you mention. Other hand you can create id for new table with auto-increment and uid for old table data.